# How to remove extra padding around AppBar leading icon in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In my Flutter app, I have this AppBar

```
Widget setAppBar(){
  return new AppBar(
    title: addAppBarTextWidget('Explore'),
    elevation: 0.0,
    leading: addLeadingIcon(),
    actions: <Widget>[
      addAppBarActionWidget(Constant.iconNotification, 22.0, 16.0, 8.0),
      addAppBarActionWidget(Constant.iconProfile, 30.0, 30.0, 15.0)
    ],
  );
}

Widget addLeadingIcon(){
  return new Container(
    height: 25.0,
    width: 25.0,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    child: new Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Image.asset(
          Constant.iconNotification,
          width: 25.0,
          height: 25.0,
        ),
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              onLeadingShowCategoryClick();
            }
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**it looks like:**

[image]

> As you can see on the AppBar, there is some extra padding around the
>   leading icon. How can I remove this extra padding.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can't do this because it is a predefined widget.
You can, however, do this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Don't show the leading button
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      // Your widgets here
    ],
  ),
),
```

Where `automaticallyImplyLeading: true` hides the leading `IconButton` so you can add your own widgets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I met some similar issue, this helps a lot. BTW, I fixed the leading and trailing widget gap by this solution.

Comment: I wanted an app bar with only two buttons. This helped me with the main axis alignment. Thank you Adrian.

Answer (score 155):

Just add a property called titleSpacing,

Sample

```
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.android),
        titleSpacing: 0,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
```

Comment: It removes padding/margin before title, not extra padding around the leading icon.

Comment: I know that this maybe isn't the answer to the question of the OP, but was the answer for the result I wanted to achieve, that was having the title sticking exactly to the left with no margin.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer. this solution keeps the default behavior of the app bar. the app bar shows menu button or back button depending on the navigator by default. see here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html

Answer (score 44):

[image]

**Short answer:**

```dart
AppBar(
  leadingWidth: 8, // <-- Use this
  centerTitle: false, // <-- and this
  leading: Icon(Icons.android),
  title: Text('Title'),
)
```

---

**More customizations:**

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(-15, 0),
    child: Icon(Icons.android),
  ),
  titleSpacing: -30,
  centerTitle: false,
  title: Text("Title"),
)
```

and if you don't want to use any leading widget:

[image]

```dart
AppBar(
  title: Text('Title'),
  centerTitle: false,
  titleSpacing: 0,
)
```

Comment: Setting leadingWidth small values makes the back button not clickable

Answer (score 16):

Adding Title Spacing will solve this.

```
 AppBar(
   centerTitle: false,
   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
   titleSpacing: 0
 )
```

Answer (score 12):

Complete working workaround with some input from Adrian.

[image: Working Sample]

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    titleSpacing: 0.0,
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        ),
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
              onPressed: _onClickNotification,
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 12.0,
              right: 10.0,
              width: 10.0,
              height: 10.0,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: AppColors.notification,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(child: Text('test')),
        )
      ],
    ),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Online'),
          Switch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: _buildDrawer(),
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.orange,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 10):

just set `titleSpacing` and `automaticallyImplyLeading` for remove space

like

```
AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
)
```

Comment: Both of these properties are mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942351/12483095) post, please don't add same answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this, this works fine. when you set the leading = null then extra space of leading widget will remove.

```
appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: null,
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        title: new Text("title"),
      ),
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to move the icon a bit to the left like I did, you can still use the leading property and just set the alignment on the IconButton:

```
    leading: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return IconButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          icon: MyIcon(),
          alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0.0), // move icon a bit to the left
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

For the Sliver Appbar Padding

```
  sliver: SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 400.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: false,
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              title: Text('Appbar'),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: `titlePadding` inside `FlexibleSpaceBar` helped me !! thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use Widgets from Material package, they are defined respecting Material Design specification [document](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#specs). So if your modification violates this spec, you have to build your own Widget instead of using the Material Widgets.

Comment: In the Material Design specification, I read nothing about extra padding for the leading icon. Both sides have 16 dps.