# How to add a drawer and a search icon on my app bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and exploring it. I already have an app bar but I can't seem to figure out how to properly display a drawer icon and a search icon on it. I want it to look like the gmail app bar like the image below. I am working on a company helpdesk mobile app. Thanks.

[image: gmail app bar]

Comment: This question can be easily solved by simply checking the flutter documentation https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/basic-app-bar/ and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html

Comment: Upgraded version => https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942351/4362756

Answer (score 24):

Do it as stated in the [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html).

```
new AppBar( 
    title: new Text('My Fancy Dress'), 
    actions: <Widget>[ 
        new IconButton( icon: new Icon(Icons.playlist_play), tooltip: 'Air it', onPressed: _airDress, ),],
    leading: <Widget>[
        new IconButton( icon: new Icon(Icons.playlist_play), tooltip: 'Air it', onPressed: _airDress, ),
], )
```

Where the widget under leading is the drawer and the one under actions is the search iconbutton.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this code....

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context){
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {

                },
              );
            }),
        title: Text("Flutter App"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest**

```
appBar: AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        onPressed: () {
        },
      )
    ],
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    title: Text(
      "Your title",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: @mate00 It is an AppBar with actions (containing search icon, person icon, and detection), with centered title and background color,