# Making Icon center of FlattButton issue after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make this arrow icon in the center of the button

[image]

it's see the edge of icon is the center of icon, and I want make flutter see the center of icon is the center of icon

for more explain:

[image]

my code:

```
AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      leading:
      // Here the code of the button
       SizedBox(
        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
        width: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // ....
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: favFlag ? Colors.red : Colors.red[100],
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              favFlag = !favFlag;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

And it's was working with me before last upgrade.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460629/how-to-remove-extra-padding-around-appbar-leading-icon-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with the use of your `height` and `width` factor for `SizedBox`. I used simple values for these and it is working fine.

In fact, I removed the `SizedBox` widget and there was no such effect. I have attached the pic after the code as well :)

```
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading:
            // Here the code of the button
            SizedBox(
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: favFlag ? Colors.red : Colors.red[100],
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
               favFlag = !favFlag;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I took your code copy and past and still not working

Comment: did you upgrade flutter to 1.22?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Flutter 1.22, try flutter clean and rebuild your app

Comment: I did and tried it in new screen and still not at center

Comment: Can you try it in new project? As testing purpose see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
 AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      // Here the code of the button

      leading: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: FlatButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Positioned.directional(
                textDirection: Directionality.of(context),
                end: 3,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // ....
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: favFlag ? Colors.red : Colors.red[100],
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              favFlag = !favFlag;
            });
            AdsService.listByPagination();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I've positioned it to center manually, so I prefer if there an another clean short solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Icons.arrow_back_ios,`

use `Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined`

It should work