# How to set the space in AppBar evenly on phone and websites

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, size, space

I have dropdownbutton, container and other widgets, and i wanna make the same space between them

```
AppBar(
      elevation: widget.isElevated ? 5 : 0,
      foregroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      actions: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.timeline_sharp),
              tooltip: 'FSA Store',
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              tooltip: 'MarketPlace',
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: May you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460629/how-to-remove-extra-padding-around-appbar-leading-icon-in-flutter

Comment: or you can set your actions at the title attribute with Row()